# Angular 5 - Stop errors from undefined object before loading data

Tags: angular, typescript

What's the best way to prevent errors in console from objects that are still undefined?

Let's say I have this

```
name : string;
constructor(private data: DataService) {
this.data.name.subscribe(res => this.name = res);
}
```

Inside my html I have this

```
<p> {{name}}</p>
```

When I load the page I get `_co.name` is not defined, but the page still shows the value of `name`. The component is loading before getting the data I suppose.

What's the best approach to prevent this?

I saw `ngIf` is not `null` or something like that, is an option. But then I saw something about Resolve.

Comment: It would be better to paste actual call context.... so template mb?

Comment: Use an object instead set to null and check if set in the html {{ info?.name }}
EDIT : I don't get what is _co but you can also try _co?.name

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Multiple ways: You can use any one suitable to you.

**1. Adding ngIf** : If `name` is `undefined` or `null` or `''` it will not render the element and prevent errors in console. When `name` gets defined value it will automatically update the view.

`*ngIf="name"`

**2. Adding async pipe** : View will update whenever `name` gets defined. It waits for `name` to get defined (or resolved). (name should be a promise or an observable for this to work.)

`{{ name | async }}`

**3. Adding fallback value** : This is simply `or` condition. If `name` is `undefined` or `null` or `''` , you can decide which fallback value to assign .
`{{ name || "" }}`

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for

Comment: @kachus22 Great, can you accept the answer? You can click on the gray tick mark to make it green. So it becomes accepted answer.

Comment: how to do it with [(ngModel)] = "a.b.c" where we cant use ? operator

Comment: Point 2 is wrong. name is a string, not a promise or an observable. Hence you cannot you async pipe on it. https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Answer (score 6):

Just initialize your variable

```
name : string = "";
```

or you can do it inside of the constructor

```
this.name = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in previous responses you can use `{{ name | async }}` but remember if you want to use `{{ name | async }}`, name must be a promise or an observable.
Otherwise you'll get an error like this :

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'xxx' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{{name?.value}}` or `{{name?}}` inside component.html.
Can make treatment to like this in compoment.ts ↓

`````
   ````

    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map((param: ParamMap) => {
        // @ts-ignore
        return param.params.id;
      })
    ).subscribe(prodId => {
      this.id = prodId;
      this.productService.getSingleProduct(this.id).subscribe(prod => {
        this.product = prod;
        if (prod.images !== null) {
          this.thumbimages = prod.images.split(';');
        }`enter code here`
      });
    });


  ````
`````