# How to fix '_co.x is undefined' error in Angular?

Tags: json, angular

I have a form which sends data to a database. But I'm having trouble with nested JSON objects.

I've tried the `*ngIf` statement as suggested by [Angular 5 - Stop errors from undefined object before loading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473238/angular-5-stop-errors-from-undefined-object-before-loading-data/50473485).
The view is supposed to update once the object defined, however it never updates. So there must be a fault in my code.

**customer.ts** (model)

```
export class Customer {
  public name: string
  public contactDetails:
  {
    phone: number,
    email: string
  }
}
```

**customer.component.ts**

```
private customer: Customer;

constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

createCustomer()
{
    this.customerService.postCustomer(this.customer).subscribe
    (
      data=>
      {
        console.log(data)
      },
      error=>
      {
        console.log(error)
      }
    )
}
```

**customer.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="customer.name" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group" *ngIf="customer.contactDetails">
  <label>Phone number</label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="customer.contactDetails.phone">
</div>
```

Only the `name` input works. If I use `*ngIf="customer"`, I get the error `_co.customer.contactDetails is undefined`.

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in stackblitz? and provide a link here. @Paprika

Comment: you can use async pipe too, since the customer field is not available at the time of rendering, cause you are using a subscription + Observable which will emit the value of customer at some point of time, until then it will be always undefined.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyt1nf 
I had trouble importing the service for some reason. So I couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

try :  *ngIf="customer.contactDetails | async " and let me know, if it does work or not?

Comment: Thanks for response! The error went away, but the `phone` textbox doesn't load

Comment: ok as per your implementation, try to define this.customer.contactDetails = some demo value , as initial data and on subscription you will get new data (m not sure how your logic is implemented). why phone is not loading cause, there is not data to represent there.

Comment: Alright, I did as you said and assigned custom values to this.customer.contactDetails. If I display the values to the console after submitting to the database, it displays the demo values. But the values I enter from the textbox don't work

Comment: try to replicate the issue in the stackblitz, will try to help you, I think its just a simple logical error.

Answer (score 0):

Use your condition instead like this -

```
*ngIf="customer?.contactDetails"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! the error message doesn't appear but the `phone` textbox doesn't appear

Comment: Console or print the value you are getting to debug it

Comment: When submitting the values entered to the textbox, nothing happens. But If I hardcode values to this.customer.contactDetails, it displays the hardcoded values. So i'm not entirely sure what's going on here

Comment: In these type of scenarios you must use form, it would be a better approach

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to overcome undefined property in object is create empty customer object using `new Customer()`

**customer.component.ts**

```
  private customer: Customer = new Customer();

constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

createCustomer()
{
    this.customerService.postCustomer(this.customer).subscribe
    (
      data=>
      {
        console.log(data)
      },
      error=>
      {
        console.log(error)
      }
    )
}
```

Comment: Have you heard of DI?

Comment: yes I know that but here if you are creating modal with class then you can create empty object using new keyword

Comment: Thanks for the response! using this results in a `_co.customer.queueCreds is undefined` error again. I'm having a lot of trouble with nested object